# Рекурсивный поиск по маске C++.Необходимо в функцию в качестве параметра передать маску для поиска

Tags: c++, visual-studio, поиск, рекурсия

В качестве аргумента необходимо допилить маску для поиска, ума не приложу как это сделать, ведь если в строку Find = FindFirstFile((dir + "\*").c_str(), &FileData); вписать маску, она будет перекрывать дальнейший поиск в подкаталогах.К примеру добавить счетчик глубины ? Буду безумно благодарен за помощь.

```
void FindFiles(string dir)
{
    string ster = " "; // path container
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FileData;
    hFind = FindFirstFile((dir + "\\*").c_str(), &FileData);

    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if (FileData.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if (FileData.cFileName[0] == '.')
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Directory: " << FileData.cFileName << std::endl;
                    FindFiles(dir + "\\" + FileData.cFileName + "\\");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ster = dir + "\\" + FileData.cFileName + "\\"; // костыль
                ster.erase(ster.end() - 1);
                //if (strinf(text, ster) == 1) return ster;
                std::cout << FileData.cFileName << "                               "
                          << ster << strinf("qwe", ster) << std::endl;
            }
        }
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FileData));
    }

    //return "no such files";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понимаю, что вам не нравится - у вас почти полностью работоспособный код.
Вот, после небольшой подчистки (+ добавил вам счетчик глубины рекурсии) вполне работает:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


void FindFiles(string dir, int depth) {
    string ster=" ";// path container
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FileData;
    hFind = FindFirstFile((dir + "\\*").c_str(), &FileData);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if (FileData.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if (FileData.cFileName[0] == '.')
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Depth: " << depth << "   Directory: " << FileData.cFileName << std::endl;
                    FindFiles(dir + "\\" + FileData.cFileName,depth+1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << dir << FileData.cFileName << std::endl;
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FileData));
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FindFiles("c:\\Windows",0);
}
```

Я не стал поправлять, но учтите, что кроме служебных каталогов `.` и `..` может быть что-то типа `.dir`, так что ваша проверка не совсем корректна.

Comment: У меня проблема с тем что бы в функцию передавать маску для поиска, в качестве параметра void FindFiles(string dir, int depth, string mask)

Comment: Ну передавайте. Вариантов два - использовать поиск `*`, как сейчас, и проверять соответствие найденного файла маске, или второй - искать только файлы с нужной маской, а потом только подкаталоги с маской `*`.

Comment: т.е.  что то вроде if (FileData.cFileName[0] == '123*.txt') ?

Comment: Нет, надо проверка на соответствие маске. Можно воспользоваться стандартным `regexp` из C++; если это сложно - лучше делать два поиска - для `dir + "\\*"` только по каталогам, а для `dir + "\\123*.txt"` - только по файлам.

Comment: Все получилось, очень вам благодарен